# How do I find out whats wrong with elasticsearch replication when the status is red

Tags: elasticsearch, replication

I'm seeing very high CPU on my two elasticsearch nodes and profiling shows that its associated with elasticsearch replication.

I've executed the health status command:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true'
```

which returns this:

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "status" : "red",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 2,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 2,
  "active_primary_shards" : 2003,
  "active_shards" : 4006,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 34
}
```

I can see the status is red so there is some sort of problem which presumably is resulting in the high cpu.

But how do i find out what is actually wrong to i can rectify it?

Answer (score 2):

I'd start with the debugging approach outlined here:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_cluster_health.html

To recap, try running:

```
GET _cluster/health?level=indices
```

This will give you info about which indices are having issues - but in general a Red status means you have missing primary and replica shards which means you have missing data (not good).

I'd take a look at individual node health:

```
GET _nodes/stats
```

From there I'd focus on heap (memory) usage and disk usage - in particular look for a full disk. And then I'd be logging into each node separately to check disk usage.

Comment: Thanks. That has helped me identify the indices which arent working, but i'm still no wiser why, or what to do about it. There is no shortage of disk space, and i only have two nodes both of which are running. I'm on 1.2 but will soon upgrade to 1.4.1.

I've added output of an example problem index in the question

Comment: can you add more info, like how many indexes you have, how many are having problems, etc.

Comment: not exactly sure about number of indexes, some hundreds i think. the stats command shows there are 34 unassigned shards but i dont know how many problem indexes that corresponds to, or how to find out.

Comment: Following the advice below I've queried for failed indexes, and here is an example problem index:

"bran-18117496":{ "status":"red", "number_of_shards":5, "number_of_replicas":1, "active_primary_shards":0, "active_shards":0, "relocating_shards":0, "initializing_shards":0, "unassigned_shards":10 },